# Can't run a springboot's war file : Exec format error

Tags: spring-boot, war

I can't run a springboot's war file on a debian VPS

I get "-bash: ./odc-central-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

When I build on my computer and launch it from there, it's working fine. When I move this build on the VPS, it fails to run.

When I build it on the VPS and launch it from there, it doesn't work. But if I paste this build on my computer, it's working fine.

So I assume I should search for an issue in the VPS but I don't know where to start.

uname -a command outputs this :

```
@my computer : Linux <mycomp> 5.11.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 18 02:14:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
@VPS : Linux <myvps> 4.19.0-11-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For now I can run with the "java -jar file.war" command, but I really would like to know why I get this error (I have another similar app with another similar VPS where this building and running way works fine )

EDIT :
The war file is built with maven, here's the relevant code I guess

command line : mvn clean verify -DskipTests -Pprod

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ODC Central</name>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**,META-INF/**</warSourceIncludes>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warSourceDirectory>target/classes/static/</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

EDIT 2 : As suggested by Scott in the comment's section, I added the 'executable' line in the maven spring boot plugin conf and I was able to run the build.
Don't Know why I was able to run it before without this conf on my computer.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show how you're building the war file, like the build file configuration and output?

Comment: thanks @ScottFrederick for your hint, I edited the post

Comment: Spring Boot jar/war files are made self-executable using the Spring Boot Maven plugin (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-executable). Are you using the Spring Boot plugin in your build also, and can you show its configuration?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottFrederick !
I added <executable>true</executable> in the plugin's conf and I can run the build on the vps now.  
Don't know how it could run on my computer without this tweak though.

If you write an answer I'll gladly accept it